# Count distinct string values per key DAX

Tags: dax, daxstudio

Say I have this data structure

| Order Number | Product Type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 123 | B |
| 123 | C |
| 123 | C |
| 234 | A |
| 557 | B |
| 557 | C |

I would like to group by distinct values of product type per key so I get the following

| Order Number | Product Type Distinct Count |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 |
| 234 | 1 |
| 557 | 2 |

How do I do it in DAX? I currently have something like the below but it gives me 3 for each row since it doesn't count per Order Number

```
EVALUATE(

    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(       
        [Order Number],
        "Product Type Distinct Count", DISCTINCTCOUNT([Product Type])       
    )
)
```

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this **calculated table** instead:

```
# Distinct Product Types = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Order Number],
    "Count", DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Product Type])
)
```

[image]

Comment: But what do I put as 'Table' if the metrics and fields in my database are TableA[Order Number] and TableB[Product Type]? Thanks

Comment: That's actually a new question for a new post with details about the relationship, but you can probably use SUMMARTIZECOLUMNS as a preparatory step.